# Using a database populated select in a form collection

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have made a form collection based on the one in the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html). Then I have made a select that is populated from a database and also based on the example from the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html#handling-dependencies). Both works by them self but now I want to use the select in the form collection and then I get the following error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
Application\Form\ClientSelectFieldset::__construct() must be an instance of 
Application\Model\ClientTable, none given, called in 
/home/path/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Form/FormElementManager.php
on line 174 and defined in
/home/path/module/Application/src/Application/Form/ClientSelectFieldset.php on line 9
```

It feels like the `init()` isn't run correctly or something, is there something special I need to do get my select to work in form collections?

Module.php

```
public function getFormElementConfig() {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Application\Form\ClientSelectFieldset' => function($sm) {
                $serviceLocator = $sm->getServiceLocator();
                $clientTable = $serviceLocator->get('Application\Model\ClientTable');
                $fieldset = new ClientSelectFieldset($clientTable);
                return $fieldset;
            }
        )
    );
}
```

src/Application/Form/ClientFieldset.php

```
<?php
namespace Application\Form;

use Application\Model\ClientTable;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;

class ClientSelectFieldset extends Fieldset {

    public function __construct(ClientTable $clientTable) {
        parent::__construct('clientselectfieldset');

        $options = array();
        $options[] = array('value' => 0, 'label' => "Select client");
        $options[] = array('value' => -1, 'label' => "---------------", 'disabled' => 'disabled');
        foreach($clientTable->fetchAll() as $clientRow) {
            $options[] = array('value' => $clientRow->id, 'label' => $clientRow->name);
        }

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Client',
                'options' => $options,
            ),
        ));
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
        return array(
            'id' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => array(
                    array('name' => 'Int'),
                ),
            )
        );
    }
}
```

src/Application/Form/InvoiceFieldset.php

```
<?php
namespace Application\Form;

use Application\Model\Invoice;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods as ClassMethodsHydrator;


class InvoiceFieldset extends Fieldset {
    ... more code ...

    public function init() {
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'client',
            'type' => 'Application\Form\ClientSelectFieldset'
        ));
    }
}
```

src/Application/Form/InvoiceForm.php

```
<?php

namespace Application\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods as ClassMethodsHydrator;

class InvoiceForm extends Form {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('invoice-form');
        ... more code ...

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Application\Form\InvoiceFieldset',
            'options' => array(
                'use_as_base_fieldset' => true
            )
        ));
        ... more code ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code for your classes so that we could help you

Comment: The form element manager is creating your fieldset as an "invokable" and therefore will not inject the `ClientTable` as a dependency.You will need to have the fieldset registered with a service *factory*.

Comment: Code added, i hope that helps.

Comment: @AlexP: Based on the code I added do i need to add one more factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple, i had to move the declaration of `Application\Form\InvoiceFieldset` in the class `InvoiceForm` from the `__construct()` to the `init()` function.

src/Application/Form/InvoiceForm.php

```
<?php

namespace Application\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods as ClassMethodsHydrator;

class InvoiceForm extends Form {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('invoice-form');
        ... more code ...
    }

    public function init() {
        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Application\Form\InvoiceFieldset',
            'options' => array(
                'use_as_base_fieldset' => true
            )
        ));
    }
}
```